# ORA-00928 missing select keyword ora-06512 at dbms_sql at line 1120 load_csv at line 84

Tags: oracle

dbms_sql is throwing error at dbms.parse().

[form error]

I'm getting this error while trying to upload a CSV file into Oracle 12c database table.it is failing at dbms_sql.parse() function because I'm giving insert query as an argument instead of

load_csv code is attached.

```
   create or replace FUNCTION load_csv ( p_table in varchar2,
 p_dir in varchar2 DEFAULT 'THINS_UPD' ,
 P_FILENAME in varchar2 ,
 p_ignore_headerlines IN INTEGER DEFAULT 1,
 p_delimiter in varchar2 default ',',
 p_optional_enclosed in varchar2 default '"' )
 return number
 is
/***************************************************************************
-- PROCEDURE LOAD_CSV
-- PURPOSE: This Procedure read the data from a CSV file.
-- And load it into the target oracle table.
-- Finally it renames the source file with date.
--
-- P_FILENAME
-- The name of the flat file(a text file)
--
-- P_DIRECTORY
-- Name of the directory where the file is been placed.
-- Note: The grant has to be given for the user to the directory
-- before executing the function
--
-- P_IGNORE_HEADERLINES:
-- Pass the value as '1' to ignore importing headers.
--
-- P_DELIMITER
-- By default the delimiter is used as ','
-- As we are using CSV file to load the data into oracle
--
-- P_OPTIONAL_ENCLOSED
-- By default the optionally enclosed is used as '"'
-- As we are using CSV file to load the data into oracle
--
**************************************************************************/
 l_input utl_file.file_type;

 l_lastLine varchar2(4000);
 l_cnames varchar2(4000);
 l_bindvars varchar2(4000);
 l_status integer;
 l_cnt number default 0;
 l_rowCount number default 0;
 l_sep char(1) default NULL;
 L_ERRMSG varchar2(4000);
 V_EOF BOOLEAN := false;
l_theCursor number default dbms_sql.open_cursor;
v_insert varchar2(1100);
 begin

 l_cnt := 1;
 for TAB_COLUMNS in (
 select column_name,data_type from user_tab_columns where table_name=p_table order by column_id
 ) loop
 l_cnames := l_cnames || tab_columns.column_name || ',';
 --Dbms_Output.put_line(tab_columns.column_name ||'colname');
-- l_bindvars := l_bindvars || case when tab_columns.data_type in ('DATE', 'TIMESTAMP(6)') then 'to_date(:b' || l_cnt || ',"YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS"),' else ':b'|| l_cnt || ',' end;
 l_bindvars := l_bindvars || case when tab_columns.data_type in ('DATE', 'TIMESTAMP(6)') then ':b'|| l_cnt || ',' else ':b'|| l_cnt || ',' end;

 l_cnt := l_cnt + 1;
 end loop;
 l_cnames := rtrim(l_cnames,',');
 L_BINDVARS := RTRIM(L_BINDVARS,',');

 L_INPUT := UTL_FILE.FOPEN( P_DIR, P_FILENAME, 'r' );
 IF p_ignore_headerlines > 0
 THEN
 BEGIN
 FOR i IN 1 .. p_ignore_headerlines
 LOOP
 UTL_FILE.get_line(l_input, l_lastLine);
 END LOOP;
 EXCEPTION
 WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
 THEN
 v_eof := TRUE;
 end;
 END IF;
 v_insert :='insert into ' || p_table || '(' || l_cnames || ') values (' || l_bindvars || ')';
Dbms_Output.put_line(l_theCursor||'cursor'||l_bindvars||'---'||l_cnames);

 if not v_eof THEN
 Dbms_Output.put_line(l_theCursor||'-'||'insert into ' || p_table || '(' || l_cnames || ') values (' || l_bindvars || ')');--Akash added
 --dbms_sql.parse( l_theCursor, 'insert into ' || p_table || '(' || l_cnames || ') values (' || l_bindvars || ');' dbms_sql.native );
 DBMS_SQL.parse(l_theCursor ,v_insert, dbms_sql.native );
  Dbms_Output.put_line(112);
 loop
 begin
 utl_file.get_line( l_input, l_lastLine );
 exception
 when NO_DATA_FOUND then
 exit;
 end;

 if length(l_lastLine) > 0 then
 for i in 1 .. l_cnt-1
 LOOP

 dbms_sql.bind_variable( l_theCursor, ':b'||i,
 rtrim(rtrim(ltrim(ltrim(
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(l_lastline,'(^|,)("[^"]*"|[^",]*)',1,i),p_delimiter),p_optional_enclosed),p_delimiter),p_optional_enclosed));
 end loop;
 begin
 l_status := dbms_sql.execute(l_theCursor);

 l_rowCount := l_rowCount + 1;
 exception
 when OTHERS then
 L_ERRMSG := SQLERRM;
 insert into BADLOG ( TABLE_NAME, ERRM, data, ERROR_DATE )
 values ( P_TABLE,l_errmsg, l_lastLine ,systimestamp );
 end;
 end if;
 end loop;

 dbms_sql.close_cursor(l_theCursor);
 utl_file.fclose( l_input );
 commit;
 end if;
 insert into IMPORT_HIST (FILENAME,TABLE_NAME,NUM_OF_REC,IMPORT_DATE)
 values ( P_FILENAME, P_TABLE,l_rowCount,sysdate );
 Dbms_Output.put_line(P_DIR||'-'||P_FILENAME);--added by Akash

 RETURN L_ROWCOUNT;
 end LOAD_CSV;
```

Comment: in which line the error is coming? what is the exact message?

Comment: I think this probably has something to do with the column names for the table you're trying to run it against. Does it have quoted identifiers, or column names which are also keywords? If you edit your question to include the DDL for the table that's causing the error we might be able to spot what specifically is upsetting it.

Comment: error is in this line `DBMS_SQL.parse(l_theCursor ,v_insert, dbms_sql.native );`